# Triggers are calculating the wrong sum, giving unexpected results

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a weird issue with my Trigger. There are 2 tables: `Table A` and `Table B`.

Whenever a row is inserted to `Table A` sum of a column in this table is inserted into `Table B`

It was working fine at first, but recently I noticed when >1 rows are inserted at the exact time for a user, the trigger returns sum in a weird way.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_something` AFTER INSERT ON `Table_A` 

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    DECLARE sum BIGINT(20);

    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(number), 0) INTO sum FROM Table_A WHERE `user` = NEW.user;

    UPDATE Table_B SET sum_number = sum WHERE id = NEW.id;

END
```

Example:

### Table A

User X has a sum of `15` currently, then (with almost no delay in between):

1. Number `5` is inserted for him
2. Number `7` is inserted for him

### Table B

On this table where we hold the sum, sum for this user was `15`

Trigger updates this table in this way:

1. `20`
2. `22` <--- Wrong, this should be `27`

As you can see there isn't any number `2` inserted, it adds 7-5 = 2 for some reason.

How is that possible and why does it subtract 5 from 7 and add 2 to the sum instead of normally adding 7?

## Edit 1:

> Warning: This won't work, check the accepted answer instead

One of answers suggested select for update method.

Will this `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` affect the performance negatively in a huge way?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_something` AFTER INSERT ON `Table_A` 

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    DECLARE sum BIGINT(20);

    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(number), 0) INTO sum FROM Table_A WHERE `user` = NEW.user FOR UPDATE; 

    UPDATE Table_B SET sum_number = sum WHERE id = NEW.id;

END
```

Basically we only add `FOR UPDATE` to the end of SELECT line like this and it will perform Row Lock in InnoDB to fix the issue?

`SELECT IFNULL(SUM(number), 0) INTO sum FROM Table_A WHERE user = NEW.user FOR UPDATE;`

#### Edit 2 (Temporary Fix):

In case some one needs a very quick ***temporary*** fix for this before doing the actual & logical suggested fix: What I did was to put a random `usleep(rand(1,500000))` before INSERT query in PHP to reduce the chance of simultaneous inserts.

Comment: Is there a relation between `Table_A.id` and `Table_A.user`? Does the value of the one determine the value of the other in both directions? Otherwise you would get inconsistencies for other reasons as well.

Comment: Yes they are the same: `User ID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that the inserted data is only committed to the database when the trigger finishes executing. So when both insert operations (5 and 7) execute the trigger in parallel, they read the data as it is in their transaction, i.e. the committed data with the changes made in their own transaction, but not the changes made in any other ongoing transaction.

The committed data in table A sums up to 20 for both transactions, and to that is added the record that is inserted in their own transaction. For the one this is 5, for the other it is 7, but as these records were not yet committed, the other transaction does not see this value.

That is why the sum is 20+5 for the one, and 20+7 for the other. The transactions then both update table B, one after the other (because table B will be locked during an update and until the end of the transaction), and the one that is latest "wins".

To solve this, don't read the sum from table A, but keep a running sum in Table B:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_something` AFTER INSERT ON `Table_A` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Table_B SET sum_number = sum_number + NEW.number WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
/
```

I suppose you already have triggers for `delete` and `update` on `Table_B`, as otherwise you'd have another source of inconsistencies.

So these need to be (re)written too:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_something` AFTER DELETE ON `Table_A` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Table_B SET sum_number = sum_number - OLD.number WHERE id = OLD.id;
END;
/
CREATE TRIGGER `update_something` AFTER UPDATE ON `Table_A` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Table_B SET sum_number = sum_number - OLD.number WHERE id = OLD.id;
    UPDATE Table_B SET sum_number = sum_number + NEW.number WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
/
```

This way you prevent to lock potentially many rows in your triggers.

Then, after you have done the above, you can fix the issues from the past, and do a one-shot update:

```
update Table_B
join   (select   id, user, ifnull(sum(number),0) sum_number 
        from     Table_A 
        group by id, user) A
     on Table_B.id = A.id
    and Table_B.sum_number <> A.sum_number
set     Table_B.sum_number = A.sum_number;
```

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer kind sir, as some members might already have wrong sums in this large database because of this issue, may I ask what would you think about my `Edit 1`? because this way still the next time a raw is inserted, the member will have the correct sum.

Comment: "Edit 1" would work, but it would lock potentially many rows in Table A, and this lock remains until the end of the transaction, so also while the update in Table B happens. I have added a section to my answer on how I would fix the existing inconsistencies with a one-shot operation (after you have implemented the changes to the triggers).

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you put into this. I understand everything now.

Answer (score 1):

You get this because of the race condition in the trigger. Both triggeres are fired at the same time, thus `SELECT` returns the same value for both of them - 15. Then first trigger updates tha value adding 5 and resulting in 20, and then the second update is run with 15 + 7 = 22.

What you should do is use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` instead. This way if first trigger issues the select, then the second one will have to wait until first one finishes.

EDIT:

Your question made me think, and maybe using `FOR UPDATE` is not the best solution. According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

> For index records the search encounters, SELECT ... FOR UPDATE locks the rows and any associated index entries, the same as if you issued an UPDATE statement for those rows.

And because you are selecting the sum of entries from `Table A` it will lock those entries, but will still allow inserting new ones, so the problem would not be solved.

It would be better to operate only on data from `Table B` inside the trigger, as suggested by [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot).

Comment: Thank you, but as there are a lot of inserts, I think these locks might slow down the whole website?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be table lock in InnoDB or Row lock? If it's row lock then its really fine, would you kindly check if my updated question is correct based on this?

Comment: I see, thanks anyway for that, I had never heard of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` before. Good to learn new stuff.